# how to run this command from (ssh server qstat -f )java program?

Tags: java

I am trying to run commands in a remote host through a Java program but  I am NOT able to execute commands . Do you have any recommendations? I am working on a Windows OS

```
Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runtime.exec("root@10.117.217.160");

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
Thread.sleep(3000);

while (in.ready()) {
    String s = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}

out.println("ls /home/ubuntu");
Thread.sleep(3000);

while (in.ready()) {
    String s = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
out.println("exit");
```

Comment: What code have you used? How is it failing? What else have you tried?

Comment: Why its tag [tag:python] question ?

Comment: This is the code i have written.

Comment: Process p = Runtime.exec("root@10.117.217.160"); Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method exec(String) from the type Runtime

Comment: @Rahul : you should edit your question and add your code.

Comment: Now i have written new line Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process p = runtime.exec("root@10.117.217.160"); Now it's working fine.

Comment: @Rahul: There is an `edit` button under your question. Click on it, and add the code properly there in a code block. Also add every additional information in the question and not in the comments.

Comment: Do you intend to access through SSH ?